# Min-height doesn't work with calc function

Tags: css, joomla, footer

I'm building a website in Joomla 3.x. My index.php looks like this:

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="inner_wrapper">
        <div id="header"></div>
        <div id="content" class="<?php echo $active->alias; ?>">
            <div id="content_inside">
                <div id="user1"></div>
                <div id="user2"></div>
                <div id="component"></div>
                <div id="user3"></div>
                <div id="user4"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So, #header and #footer have fixed height, #content doesn't. I'm trying to get #component fill the rest of available space (or to push the #footer down to the bottom of the page when there is not enough content to push it down). I tried that with min-height in css using the calc function, but it doesn't work.

Also, note that #user1, #user2 and #user3 are used only on the home page and are not displayed on other pages. #component has fixed height one the home page.

My current CSS is:

```
body {background-color:#FAFAFA; margin: 0; padding:0; min-height:100%;}
html {min-height:100%;}
#wrapper {min-height:100%;}
#inner_wrapper {min-height:100%;}
#header {background-color: #E0E0E0; margin:0 0 0 0; height:90px;}
#user4 {background-color: #E1E1E1; margin: 0; /*height: 126px;  ----> not really here, but is generated by modules and is always like this*/}
div#footer {background-color: #151C1B; margin: 0 0 0 0; width: 100%; /*height: 430px;  ----> not really here, but is generated by the module and is always like this*/}
```

So, I applied this code to the #component:

```
#component {
    min-height: -moz-calc(100% - 646px);
    min-height: -webkit-calc(100% - 646px);
    min-height: calc(100% - 646px);
}
```

It doesn't work. Also, I checked and nothing overrides the min-height property.

What should I do? Any other options to achieve this effect?

Thanks!

Comment: My guess would be that it is not clear what the `100%` in your `calc` function are actually meant to be, because the ancestor element does not have a height set.

Comment: Hm, yeah. You're right. I went through all ancestor elements and set height or calculate it where needed it, not it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would not used CSS33 for this as you have to manually define the height of the header and footer to then be able to set the height for the content. Yes, this is feasible, however it's not a dynamic way of doing it.

For this, I would use jQuery which gets shipped with your Joomla package. To import jQuery, simply include the following in your index.php:

```
JHtml::_('jquery.framework');
```

Then, you can use the following jQuery:

```
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();
$js = "
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){

        var viewportHeight  = $(window).height();     /* Get viewport height */
        var headerHeight    = $('#header').height();  /* Get header height */
        var footerHeight    = $('#footer').height();  /* Get footer height */

        /* Calculate the height */
        var calculate = viewportHeight - parseInt(headerHeight + footerHeight);

        /* Apply the calculate height to the component element */
        $('#component').height(calculate);

    });
";
$doc->addScriptDeclaration($js);
```

All of the above code needs to be added to your index.php at the top within `<?php ?>` tags

Hope this helps